# GET Requests to S3 files "pending" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, amazon-s3

My site is currently using an S3 cloud to store my audio and image files. For every post in the blog roll of my site, each post will request an image file and an audio file. When you load a page initially the first set of posts will have all the image and audio files requested successfully.

When I scroll down to load more posts (using waypoints infinite scroll), only a couple of posts will load their resources. The other requests are stuck in "pending", which also only for the files being requested from my S3. When I try loading the 3rd batch of posts, none of the resources are loaded, and all the requests to those resources stuck in pending. Though performance is not ideal right now, I do not have any issues like this in Firefox or Safari/IE. I've seen this issue discussed in regard to HTML5 video, but this seems to be me to be something related to S3.

I have also tried adding a CDN to serve the files but that didnt make a difference either. Any ideas? An affected page is https://rapify.co/charts/, if youd want to test it yourself. Thanks! Just a note the audio file is displayed as waveform, so if the waveform loads, the GET request was successfully completed.

Comment: It looks like your site is working ok now, but I don't see any direct requests to S3 in your network requests. Are you just making a request to your server and letting it fetch the assets?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I actually found the solution to this a while back: The pending requests were usually for audio files, and I solved this problem by converting all the files to a 128kbps bitrate. That way the files completed loading after a couple of seconds.